# Find $P(A)$ given $P(A \cup B), P(B)$

Tags: probability

So I'm trying to find out what $P(A)$ is, given that $P(A\cup B) = 0.28$ and $P(B) = 0.05$.

It is also given that $P(A\mid B) = P(A)$ (they are independent)

I'm not quite sure how to go on about this, as $P(A) P(A\mid B) = P(A\cap B)$ but that doesn't help me much.

Would appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\mathbb P(A\mid B)= \mathbb P(A)$, we have $\mathbb P(A\cap B)=\mathbb P(B)\cdot\mathbb P(A\mid B)=\mathbb P(B)\cdot\mathbb P(A)$.

Then from the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle it follows that

$$\mathbb P(A\cup B)=\mathbb P(A)+\mathbb P(B)-\mathbb P(A\cap B)$$
$$\implies\mathbb P(A\cup B)=\mathbb P(A)+\mathbb P(B)-\mathbb P(B)\cdot\mathbb P(A)$$
$$\implies 0.28=\mathbb P(A)+0.05-0.05\cdot\mathbb P(A)$$

Can you now solve for $\mathbb P(A)?$

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

It holds that
\begin{align}
P(A\cup B)&=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)\\
&\overset{indep.}{=}P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B)
\end{align}

Substitute the given values and solve for $P(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

Since $A$ and $B$ are independent then the following equality also holds:
$$
\Pr\{A^c\cap B^c\}=\Pr\{A^c\}\cdot \Pr\{B^c\}
$$
So
$$
\Pr\{(A\cup B)^c\}=1-0.28=\Pr\{A^c\cap B^c\}=(1-\Pr\{A\})\cdot (1-\Pr\{B\})
$$
Solve for $\Pr\{A\}$